# Is possible to build a MLP model with the tidymodels framework?

Tags: tidymodels, mlp

According to [documentation](https://parsnip.tidymodels.org/reference/mlp.html), there are three engines for fitting MLP models in tidymodels, but all of them (as I understand) can define only one hidden layer. Am I missing some engine, incorporated in the tidymodels ecosystem, that makes available multi (hidden) layer feed forward networks? In [sklearn.neural_network](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/classes.html#module-sklearn.neural_network) fashion.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do this with the new-ish tidymodels package [brulee](https://tidymodels.github.io/brulee/), which uses [torch](https://torch.mlverse.org/). You specify the [number of layers and hidden units together](https://tidymodels.github.io/brulee/reference/brulee_mlp.html):

> **hidden_units**: An integer for the number of hidden units, or a vector of integers. If a vector of integers, the model will have `length(hidden_units)` layers each with `hidden_units[i]` hidden units.

```r
library(tidymodels)
library(brulee)

data("parabolic")

set.seed(1)
parabolic_split <- initial_split(parabolic)
parabolic_tr <- training(parabolic_split)
parabolic_te <- testing(parabolic_split)

set.seed(2)
cls_fit <- brulee_mlp(
  class ~ ., data = parabolic_tr, 
  ## two layers with 5 hidden units each:
  hidden_units = c(5, 5),
  epochs = 50L, learn_rate = 0.1, batch_size = 2^8
)

grid_points <- seq(-4, 4, length.out = 100)
grid <- crossing(X1 = grid_points, X2 = grid_points)

predict(cls_fit, grid, type = "prob") %>%
  bind_cols(grid) %>%
  ggplot(aes(X1, X2)) +
  geom_contour(aes(z = .pred_Class1), breaks = 1/2, col = "black") +
  geom_point(data = parabolic_te, aes(col = class))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-05-22 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: This is kind what I was hoping to see. The fitting occurs inside the `brulee_mlp()` function?
Also, is with `grid_points` that you can make a plot [like this one](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/325813999/figure/fig5/AS:638669773893635@1529282148432/Classification-decision-boundary-using-logistic-regression-The-blue-area-corresponds-to_Q640.jpg)? (I know this has nothing to do with the topic, but I've been searching for examples of classification regions in ggplot2 and haven't found any)

Comment: Yes, `brulee_mlp()` does fit the model (unlike a parsnip model, but you can use parsnip's `mlp()` with a brulee engine). Also yes, you can make a plot like the one you linked; I'd probably use `geom_raster()`.